# Pushing from VSTS no longer clears 'outgoing commits'

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, devops, team-explorer

Usually, after clicking `push` - the `outgoing commits` are cleared from the list. I can see on DevOps that the branch was indeed pushed, and I created a new pull request, but the commits just never leave the Team Explorer window.

I also tried

`git push`

but it didn't help.

Has anyone else experience this?

[image]

Comment: On your screenshot the branch is not even set to a remote. And where are the outgoing commits you're refering to here? Can't see any, and it's quite logical since no reference branch for push/pull seems to be defined. *(I don't use VSTS myself, these are basic questions, just see me as a rubber duck here :-)*

Comment: @RomainValeri Hi, It is definitely pushing to remote , as I can see the PR on devops. The outgoing commit  you can see in the screenshot is `added call to 'readTranches' in 'crated' hook` - it should disppear from here after pushing up. What commands can I write in git bash to provide more details?